# Modern Proguard Gradle Plugin requires Android Plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I have a java project (no android libraries).
When I use the proguard plugin on it I get an error.
I can [trace the error back to here](https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/blob/master/gradle/src/proguard/gradle/ProGuardPlugin.groovy#L47)

```
 void apply(Project project)
{
    if (!project.hasProperty('android'))
    {
        throw new BadPluginException('The ProGuard plugin requires the Android plugin to function properly.\n' +
                                     'Please specify\n    apply plugin: \'com.android.application\'\n    apply plugin: \'proguard\'')
    }
  ...
```

Is this dependency on the android plugin really necessary?

Comment: Also there is an issue in their github for this. What is happening here? After R8 release, Guardsquare should be aiming to make proguard more general as possible. https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/issues/30